# Compile JavaFx application in IntelliJ getResources() returns null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

When running the app inside IntelliJ, everything works fine.

When building artifacts, the reference to *.fxml files are not found and return when calling getClass().getResources("/path/to/fxml/file.fxml")

Executing *.jar or *.exe throws a NullPointerException: Location is not set.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In IntelliJ, go to **Project Structure -> Artifacts**
2. In Output Layout Tab, click the **+** Icon and select **Directory Content**
3. Select your **resource** directory

If this doesnt work, inside your project in IntelliJ, 
**right-click** on your **resource** directory and select **Mark Directory As..** -> **Mark as Resource Root**

Make sure your paths are in the following structure:

"/subdirectories/file.fxml"

So if your fxml-files are located at: resources/layout/main.fxml:

"/layout/main.fxml"

So **/** is your resource directory